# Problema com menu Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Fiz um menu personalizando usando o Bootstrap, no entando, estou tendo um problema quando diminuo o width para <=767px e clico no botão para expandir o menu. Eu sei que esse problema é devido a personalização do menu, alguém poderia me dar uma luz? O que pretendo é ao clicar no botão de expandir o menu ele fique com o mesmo efeito do Default do Bootstrap, na vertical e visível. Eu sei que usando a `classe="nav navbar-nav"`, esse efeito ficaria, mas estou usando a `classe="nav nav-pills"`.

[Meu menu](http://jsfiddle.net/wna34e5r/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você deseja deixar as configurações padrões do bootstrap para resoluções iguais e inferiores a 767px você pode utilizar media query para usar o seu css customizado apenas em resoluções superiores, exemplo:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  // se o seu dispositovo for maior que 768px coloque seu css
}
```

Veja [funcionando no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/wna34e5r/9/)

Outro detalhe, existe muito css inline no seu navbar, remova ele e adicione em classes, para que você possa controlar o uso delas pela resolução.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica...;)